# Bootstrap modal hides behind the modal when it calls it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap modals but when I call a second modal from the current modal it hides behind the first one.

here is my code and a link to jsfiddle

Html

```
<div id="dialog1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Dialog 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">This is the first modal dialog</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="dialog-ok" class="btn btn-default">Show dialog 2</button>          
        <button type="button" id="dialog-close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Dialog 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">This is the second modal dialog</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#dialog1").modal("show");

    $("#dialog-ok").on("click", function() {
        showDialog2();
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0302gLav/30/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a higher z-index to the second modal in your css

```
#dialog1 {
    z-index: 1999; 
}
#dialog2 {
    z-index: 2000; 
}
```

Comment: Nice it works!  I tried that before but I put z-index:0 for dialog1 and z-index:1 for dialog2. But it didn't work! What is the difference?

Comment: if you put a less z-index, maybe your page or controls on the page will have a higher z-index thus making the dialog appear behind.